# npm trust self-signed certificate

Tags: node.js, git, ssl, npm, ssl-certificate

I have a git repo on a personal server, which uses a self-signed certificate.

What I'd like to do is to add this CA to npm's trusted one(s), in order to install packages from repo like this:

```
npm install git+https://domain.tld/repo.git
```

The following commands allowed me to trust my server, but after that, my local npm does not trust npm.org repo anymore.

```
npm config set cafile=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/domain.tld/ca.crt
npm config set ca="content-of-my-cert"
```

**NB**: It works well with `git+ssh://` but as other people will consume this package, I don't want to add a new trusted ssh key every time there's a new consumer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting of the cafile and ca is wiping out the default trusted CA  certs. You can trust multiple CA certs using an array of ca[] like this:

```
npm config set ca[]="content_of_your_CA_cert"
npm config set ca[]="content_of_the_npm_root_cert"
npm config set ca[]="content_of_the_npm_intermediate_cert"
```

P.S. - npm.org is National Association of Pastoral Musicians. If you meant npmjs.com, that cert is *currently* signed by DigiCert using [this intermediate cert](https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertSHA2ExtendedValidationServerCA.crt) and [this root cert](https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yeah, I meant npmjs.com, I don't think the National Association of Pastoral Musicians is very active in node's ecosystem...